# strange behaviour of promise looping indefinitely

Tags: javascript, promise, next.js

Having this script:

```
const got = require("got");
const getStream = require("get-stream");
const app = require("express")();

async function httpGet() {
  console.log("getting response");
  let targetUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api";
  let gotOptions = {
    method: "get",
    headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
    body: undefined,
    retries: 0
  };
  let response = await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let stream = got.stream(targetUrl, gotOptions);
    stream.on("error", async error => {
      try {
        resolve(stream);
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
    stream.on("response", async res => {
      try {
        resolve(await getStream(res));
      } catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    })
  });
  return response;
}

async function apiMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const response = await httpGet();
    console.log(response);
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error("some error");
  }
  next();
}

app.use("/", [apiMiddleware]);

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ data: "some output" });
});
app.get("/someapp", (req, res) => {
  res.end();
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("listening on port 3000");
});
```

Will (upon visiting "localhost:3000/someapp") console.log

```
getting response
getting response
getting response
getting response
getting response
getting response
getting response
getting response
getting response
getting response
getting response
...
```

When debugging, the promise will always throw me at the start of `httpGet()`, so what is going on?

Comment: Just remove the resolve(stream); on error and check 
`stream.on("error", async error => { reject(err);  });`

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is going on?

You've registered the `apiMiddleware` for all routes (`/`), that includes the `/api` route. So whenever you are requesting anything from the server, `apiMiddleware()` is getting called, which will - wait for it - make a http request to `http://localhost:3000/api`! This leads to an infinite recursion. And, since you're waiting for the response before sending a response, probably also to quickly running out of memory.

Comment: So I cannot basically request anything from one server (which has middlewares set on "/") but since that would create a loop. Well the api call should be done to another server anyway (since it is api), but thanks for clarification